# Write a square-counting program

Tags: code-golf

A well-known puzzle involves counting how many squares can be made using the points on a 3x3 grid:

```
.  .  .
.  .  .
.  .  .
```

The answer is 6 — four small squares, one large square, and one square formed from the top, left, bottom, and right pegs, with edges along the *diagonals* of the squares.

Your task is to build a program that counts the total number of squares that can be formed from a set of points.

Your program will take input in one of two formats (of your choosing):

- An `M` by `N` grid  consisting of either `.` or . `.` represents a point on the grid that a square can be a corner of, and all spaces on the grid are exactly one unit apart horizontally or vertically.
- A list of coordinate pairs representing points that a square can be on.

and return the *number* of distinct squares that can be formed using the points provided. Your program must return a correct solution for every possible input.

---

For example, take the input above but where the center square is missing:

```
...
. .
...
```

There are only two possible squares here (the big one and the diagonal one), so the program should return `2`.

---

The shortest code to do this in any language wins.

Comment: I would upvote you, but your reputation is perfect. (6666) :-P

Comment: As long as I have that reputation, I'm the devil :(

Comment: Are we talking about *squares* or *rectangles*? You say the horizontal and vertical unit is both 1. But in your example, the dots are one unit apart vertically but 3 units apart horizontally. So how are those squares? Also could there be gaps in the input? If so, could you provide a more complex example?

Comment: The dots in the question are only spaced out more widely for aesthetic purposes. They should be only one character apart for purposes of the actual question.

Comment: What's the max possible value for M and N, and the max number of total points? And are we free to say how many points there are in any way we wish? (Either by taking an input at the beginning, or by stopping once some kind of EOF is reached.)

Comment: You can take inputs in the format of your choosing as long as it's one of the two types of format above, and your program should work *efficiently* for any `M` and `N` up to `300`, but it should eventually work for any value of `M` and `N` at all.

Comment: What about M,N > INT_MAX (or similar)?

Comment: M and N up to 300 means storing a character array of 90000 points in the first type of input, or 90000 coordinate pairs in the second type. That's a reasonable limitation, but a data structure of that size would normally be hard coded. So when you say "eventually" do you mean "the algorithm shall be adaptable by tweaking the constants and types in the program for any value of M and N"?

Comment: @ace: The algorithm your program uses should *theoretically* be able to solve any bounded case, but for practical limitations' sake, you can assume that M and N will be less than INT_MAX.

Comment: @steveverrill That works, I suppose.

Comment: Can the squares be rotated at angles other than 45*? e.g: a square that looks more similar to a skewed diamond?

Comment: @Ourous like 4 knight's moves in chess forming a square for example. As far as I can tell, the existing answer considers those. It will make a massive difference on the larger sizes, where you could have gradients of 1 in 100 or less.

Comment: In the first example the answer should be 5, since the last option you describe is a Rhombus (aka diamond). Like wikipedia said   "*a rhombus with right angles is a square*" Therefor the last option shouldn't count right?

Comment: No, the whole point of the original riddle is that the rhombus *is* a square because the sides are at right angles to each other.

Answer (score 7):

## Python, 95

Takes a list of coordinates from stdin.

```
l=input();print(sum((c-d+b,d+c-a)in l and(a-d+b,b+c-a)in l for a,b in l for c,d in l)-len(l))/4
```

Explanation:

> For each pair of points `(a,b)` and `(c,d)`, check if the square with additional points `(c-d+b,d+c-a)` and `(a-d+b,b+c-a)` is in the list.  This counts each square 4 times, and each point once (when `(a,b) = (c,d)`), so subtracting the number of points and dividing by 4 gives the number of squares.

Comment: Clever, concise.